# Sails.js: Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

Is it possible to use IoC in Sails?

Is there any good example and/or tutorial/documentation on this topic?

Comment: what you're describing is inheritance, not dependency injection.

Comment: You're right. I will edit the question.

Comment: as a solution, you could just use `_.extend` to mixin multiple objects in the usual way.

Comment: Can't Imagine, how to use _.extend for IoC. Ok I will try to extend my question, later...

Comment: Here is example to use classical OOP pattern using Lodash like [Travis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/291180/travis-webb) did in [sails-permission](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions/blob/master/api/controllers/AuthController.js).